# PHP tab - form validation

Tags: php, jquery

i use the code to split a form in to parts in different tabs...

```
   <?php
session_start();
require_once('./server_validation/lib.php');?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>

   <script src="./server_validation/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="./server_validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my_form').validate({
          'rules': <?php echo json_encode($validation_rules); ?>
        });
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="my_form" id="my_form" method="post" action="d1.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p> <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" /></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">

  </div>
  <input name="" type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

tabs are working fine ad i can pass the data...

tabs from source

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

But the problem is while validating the fields...

This is the working executed php file code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
   <script src="./server_validation/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="./server_validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my_form').validate({
          'rules': {"name":{"required":true,"minlength":2,"maxlength":30},"dd_number":{"required":true,"maxlength":20},"textfield":{"required":true,"minlength":2,"maxlength":30}}        });
    });
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="my_form" id="my_form" method="post" action="reg.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <label for="name"></label>




  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <label for='textarea'></label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
  <input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Submit' />


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

validation source:
http://anvweb.com/blog/server-side-form-validation-with-jquery-plugin-and-php/

Validation works fine in normal forms without tab... but not working in tabs.. wast is the problem??? thanks in advance...

Comment: can you do a fiddle please

Comment: <?php echo json_encode($validation_rules); ?> what does this return

Comment: It returns the validation rules which is done by another js script.. it works in normal forms,,, but nor working in tab formatted forms...

Comment: according to jquery validation u need to have in each input field i guess

Comment: can you paste the working code too i.e without tabs ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ve6KS/ check this and tell me the issue

Answer (score 1):

**fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/ve6KS/3/**

**Html:**

```
<form name="my_form" id="my_form" method="post" action="d1.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p> <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" /></p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <input type="text" name="dd_number" id="dd_number" />
        </div>
        <input name="" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#my_form').validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            "name": {"required": true, "minlength": 2, "maxlength": 30},
            "dd_number": {"required": true, "maxlength": 20},
            "textfield": {"required": true, "minlength": 2, "maxlength": 30}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot... working fine... But when i use the same code i can't get the result in my page.. same problem exists...

Answer (score 0):

Change the `ignore` settings in your `validate` call to a selector you don't use. by default `ignore` has ":hidden", and that's the reason why the components in hidden tabs don't get validated (i.e. they will pass, whatever their value is). by changing the ignore selector to a selector you will never use (like, e.g. ".jksfdhskhfbskeyh"), your fields will be validated as usual.